# Search folders for missing files

Tags: bash, file

I'm trying to check a bunch of folders on my NAS to see if they contain a certain file type, (movies of any kind, *mpg, avi, mkv and so on).
My script/oneliner looks like this,

```
"find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do [[ ! -f "$dir/*.avi" -o -f "$dir/*.mpg" -o -f "$dir/*.mkv" -o -f "$dir/*.iso" ]] && echo "$dir has no moviefile"; done"
```

but it doesn't seem to work properly, it catches folders that DO contain the filetypes I'm trying to screen for. And I can't check for empty folders, because some contain jpgs and .nfo files. There are some 150+ folders with subfolders in almost each.

I am using some version of busybox (BusyBox v1.16.1 (2014-12-13 05:30:51 CST)) and it's a bit crippled.

So, I wan't to check folders (1 or 2 deep) that does NOT have a movie-file in it. The subfolders are usually named extrafanart and extrathumbs, but some have more movies in them, but disregard that, I'm going to organize it in a simpler structure.

Comment: `! -f "" -o -f "" -o -f ""` isn't applying the negation to the second/etc. `-f` tests. Also if those globs are quoted that isn't going to work (and if they aren't what's the deal with the quote at the start and end of the line?). That being said you might be able to do this all with find with `-wholename` and `-prune` but I'd have to play with it to be sure.

Comment: I was trying different solutions, so thats why the code is ugly, and wrong :/ 
wholename doesn't exist in busybox, only the following: 
http://pastebin.com/z4p0RHqH

Comment: It looks like `-path` might be the same as `-wholename` but you can do it without `-wholename` it is just less clean. Something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \( -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mpg' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.iso' \) -prune -o -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u` maybe.

Comment: I'll check  this out later. Not at home right now.

Comment: Nope. This didn't work, it misses, ie no folders at all shows up, even though I know that some control folders should show up as not containing movie files.

Comment: Nope, not working. It just spat out a ".", And I know I have folders not containing any movietypes.

Comment: Can you give us a sample directory structure containing a few of each type of file and some directories that contain no matching files?

Comment: An example of how it can look; 
http://pastebin.com/VRj2uKbq

Comment: @b0red thanks for the paste bin, check my edit, it should work now.

Comment: @Bolboa, yea, it works now. Thanx for all the help. I also found that I could use -iname to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to pose a completely different solution:  Compare the list of folders with the list of folders that have your target files:

```
diff <(ls -d */) <(ls -d */* |  sed -n '/\.\(avi\|mpg\|mkv\|iso\)/s|/[^/]*$|/|p' | sort | uniq)
```

the `ls -d` commands can be replaced by equivalent find commands if you're willing to deal with a longer command in order to not potentially run into a command line length limit.

This method has the advantage that if you are searching for a large number of file types, you can just add more to the list -- it doesn't individually search for each type.

The somewhat monstrous `sed` command

1. picks out lines containing the correct file extension and
2. deletes the file name (replaces everything after the last slash with nothing)
3. prints out the result

Comment: Anchoring `$` on the `sed` address regexp?

Comment: Nope, this didn't work either, It just gave me the following error; 
-ash: syntax error: unexpected "(", even when I played around with the "(" a bit.

Comment: @b0red ash likely doesn't support process substitution so that isn't going to work at all. But if this needs to work with `ash` then that should be indicated in the post (and not tagged [tag:bash]).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it checks if the directory finds any file with the extension, if it does not find any, the echo statement is executed:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
    if [[ -z $(find "$dir" -type f -iname "*.iso" -o -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.avi" *-o -iname "*.mp4"* ) ]]
    then
        echo "$dir has no moviefile"
    fi
done
```

`-z` checks for empty strings, so if find command comes up empty-handed, it will be caught.

Moreover, in your question, you specify you want to check files one or two levels deep, if that is the case, then change `-maxdepth 1` to `-maxdepth 2`.

Comment: `find -print0` and `while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do` to be safe for paths with spaces. And that second approach is essentially what I wrote in my comment above (only with `xargs` instead of `-exec`).

Comment: The first alternative worked a bit, but it gave me a lot of false positives, so not very reliable. And it missed some folders containing .iso files. Weird.